# How do I make sub directory HTTPS in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion

How do I install HTTPS to a "login page subdirectory"? Attempted to install but it did not work. I am hesitant to install HTTPS to the main directory as the main site doesn't have any problems, only the login page needs to be HTTPS. TIA...

Comment: Is that not done at the webserver level?  If so, you should add a tag for the webserver you are using.

Comment: I believe the recommended approach these days is to switch entirely to HTTPS (Google is talking about favoring HTTPS sites over HTTP ones in search rankings). If you have a site that is worth protecting behind a login, it's worth encrypting with HTTPS.

Answer (score 2):

If you are redirecting your users to HTTP then SSL is required there are free certificates and paid for certificate (you can google search for your options).

On setting up SSL: It requires a binding your site through IIS or Apache to your cert.

Here are two articles that describe each avenue:

IIS 8 or 8.5: https://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-microsoft-iis-8.htm

Apache: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-with-a-free-signed-ssl-certificate-on-a-vps

Those should cover the basics for you.

After that you should be able to redirect your users to https://example.com/login.cfm or where ever you are taking them under HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks Frank, the certificate portion is not the problem, it's confining HTTPS to one login page and its subdirectory. It's the subdirectory portion that's got me....thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your Application.cfc add a function imposeHttps() to the onRequestStart

```
<cffunction name="onRequestStart" returnType="boolean" output="false">


    <cfset imposeHttps() />

    <!--- some of your other code --->


</cffunction>
```

and the private imposeHttps()

```
<cffunction name="imposeHttps" access="private" output="false" returntype="void">

    <cfif CGI.REQUEST_METHOD IS NOT "GET">
        <cfreturn />
    </cfif>

    <cfset var patterns = [
        "^/foo/",
        "^/bar/",
        "^/etc/",
        "^/login.cfm",
        "^/foo_secure.cfm",
        "^/some_secure.cfm"
    ] />

    <cfif REFindNoCase("(" & ArrayToList(patterns, ")|(") & ")", CGI.SCRIPT_NAME)>
        <cfif !CGI.SERVER_PORT_SECURE>
            <cflocation url="#"https://" & CGI.SERVER_NAME & CGI.SCRIPT_NAME & (CGI.QUERY_STRING EQ "" ? "" : ("?" & CGI.QUERY_STRING))#" addtoken="No">            
        </cfif>
    </cfif>

</cffunction>
```

calls to sub folders /foo , /bar, /etc are going to be imposed over https and also calls to files login.cfm, foo_secure.cfm and some_secure.cfm in root are going to be imposed secure by cflocation.

Comment: Much appreciated TechMark2K